Problema con terminal de vscode (react con vite)
Desde la terminal de windows ya pude crear un nuevo proyecto react con vite y le doy npm run dev y me funciona bien, ahora la guia de youtube me dice que lo pare con control c y lo inicie desde la terminal de vscode para facilitar estar escribiendo comandos, pero cuando le doy npm run dev desde la terminal de vscode me sale este error:  ¿cómo lo soluciono? ya que quisiera instalar tailwind también

solucion rapida, cambia de terminal.. estas en powershell, ponela en command line.. ahi arriba, a la derecha, la flechita al lado del mas donde dice powershell...
